# Sharepoint Online Excel Web Access web part refresh

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, ajax, excel-web-access-webpart

Ok i have a sharepoint list with archive data about user performance (helpdesk environment). A flow runs when an item is added to the archive list which also adds the item to an excel document. I then have graphs inside the excel document based off that data. I want to display that graph as a web part and have that graph update when a new item is added to the excel sheet. It needs to be a live graph. Is this possible? If not are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to add items to an Excel file using flow.

Add connection to SPO list in a Excel file and upload the excel file to SP Online library. Configure Refresh control for this data connection. We can refresh data automatically when opening the file or configure it to refresh automatically every specific minutes. After that, you can display the data using Excel Web Access web part.

The steps:

1. Create a excel file in client.
2. Get external data from ODate Date Feed.

   [image]
3. Link to `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/<site>/_vti_bin/listdata.svc`.
4. Select the lists which you want to display and click Next.
5. Enter the information such as file name for this data connection and click Finish.
6. View this data as you want in the workbook.
7. Edit this data connection properties, set the refresh control to refresh data when opening the file or other refresh options as you want.

   [image]
8. Save the file and upload the file to a SP Online library.
9. Display the data using Excel Web Access web part.

Comment: Ok I'll give this a try

Comment: I've got the data loading into my excel sheet but it still doesn't give me a live graph on the spo site. It updates when i refresh the page and that's the only time

Comment: There are several refresh options: Refresh every __ minutes; Refresh data when opening the file; Refresh this connection on Refresh All. You can also enable Refresh every __ minutes to refresh data at intervals of time that you specify. Refer to: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/refreshing-data-in-a-workbook-in-a-browser-window-89560193-0c11-420b-b7d8-744766ccdc94

Comment: But this doesn't seem to refresh the charts on the excel web access web part though? Only in the open excel sheet.

Comment: For this issue, we need to change the Trusted File Location settings, but it is not available in SharePoint Online. In online, we can use Power BI to get data from a file and auto refresh data. Refer to: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29014.sharepoint-error-external-data-refresh-failed-we-are-unable-to-refresh-one-or-more-data-connections-in-this-workbook-the-following-connections-failed-to-refresh.aspx